# Dynamically Find the Edge of a Rectangle

Tags: c++, c, 2d, bitwise-operators

I have 2 2D points which are jammed together into an array: `int square[4]`. These four numbers are interpreted as the definition of a rectangle with horizontal lines parallel to the X-axis and vertical lines parallel to the Y-axis. The elements of the array then respectively define:

1. Left edge's X coordinate
2. Bottom edge's Y coordinate
3. Right edge's X coordinate
4. Top edge's Y coordinate

I have defined the a winding order in this `enum`:

```
enum WindingOrder {
    BOTTOM = 0,
    RIGHT,
    TOP,
    LEFT
};
```

The minimal, complete, verifiable example of my code, is that I am given an output second array: `int output[4]` and an input `WindingOrder edge`. I need to populate `output` as follows:

```
switch(edge) {
case BOTTOM:
    output[0] = square[0]; output[1] = square[1]; output[2] = square[2]; output[3] = square[1];
    break;
case RIGHT:
    output[0] = square[2]; output[1] = square[1]; output[2] = square[2]; output[3] = square[3];
    break;
case TOP:
    output[0] = square[2]; output[1] = square[3]; output[2] = square[0]; output[3] = square[3];
    break;
case LEFT:
    output[0] = square[0]; output[1] = square[3]; output[2] = square[0]; output[3] = square[1];
    break;
}
```

I'm not married to a particular `WindingOrder` arrangement, nor do I care about the order of the points in `ouptut`, so if changing those makes this solvable I'm down. What I want to know is can I construct the `square` indexes to assign to `output` in a `for` loop, *without* an `if`/`case`/ternary statement (in other words using bit-wise operations)?

So I'd want, given `int i = 0` and `WindingOrder edge` to do bit-wise operations on them to find:

```
do {
    output[i] = array[???];
} while(++i <= LEFT);
```

**EDIT:**

I've received a lot of static array answers (which I believe are the best way to solve this so I've given a +1). But as a logic problem I'm curious how few bit-wise operations could be taken to find an element of a given edge dynamically. So for example, how should this function's body be writen given an arbitrary `edge` and `i`: `int getIndex(int i, int edge)`

Comment: @CloseVoter Can you give me a comment on what I can do to help clarify the question? It seems fairly clear-cut to me?

Comment: I dont really understand what the main problem is. If you want a rectangle out of 2 points, why do you take left X, bot Y, rigth X and top Y? If the lines are parallel to the axis, it would be sufficient to have XY of lower-left and XY of upperright corner. the lower right X would be (upperight.x -lowerleft.x) etc.. If you have 4 points at lets say the middle of the rectangle, then simply calculate the corner points like: lowerleft.x = bottom.x - (bottom.x - left.x); lowerleft.y = left.y - (left.y - bottom.y) etc.

Comment: @Eskalior I want `output` to contain an the points that would define the  edge of the original `square` requested by `WindingOrder edge`. I clearly *did* define `square` to be: `square[0]`: left X; `square[1]`: bottom Y; `square[2]`: right X; `square[3]`: top Y.

Comment: So lets say you have BOTTOM = 3 RIGHT = 4 TOP = 5 LEFT = 1 you want as result for bottom the points P(1,3) and P ( 4,3)  ?

Comment: @Eskalior So your example would define the parameters as: `square = {1, 3, 4, 5}` and `edge = BOTTOM`. And the desired result would be either `output = {1, 3, 4, 3}` as you say *or* `output = {4, 3, 1, 3}` because point order doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand the winding order... could you clarify for me please?

For example case top seems to specify that output would be {TOP, LEFT, BOTTOM, LEFT}? Was the last element meant to be RIGHT?

All the windings seem to have a duplicate edge. Could you explain what the winding order means? Thanks.

Comment: @Jimbo Sorry Eskalior's terminology was a bit confusing, because he uses the `enum` names to define the `square` coordinates, which is incorrect. If you ignore his post and just look at [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334828/dynamically-find-the-edge-of-a-rectangle?noredirect=1#comment56411738_34334828) does it make sense? Inputs of `square = {1, 3, 4, 5}` and `edge = BOTTOM` should produce either `output = {1, 3, 4, 3}` or `output = {4, 3, 1, 3}`

Comment: @JonathanMee.. Ah yes the penny has dropped, thanks

Comment: seems like an (x, y) problem to me... ;)

Comment: Why did you store your edges in the order: L, B, R, T  ; but then defined your enum as B, R, T, L ?

Comment: @M.M Cause the two are independent. The `enum` identifies what edge `output` is, and `output` is in the standard fomat of two x,y pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that possible to redefine WindingOrder's value set? If it could be , here's my solution , which tried encoding selection indexes in WindingOrder's value set , then simply decoding out select index for `input[]` by shifting and masking as long the `output[]` index iterating.

[Thanks to **chqrlie** for offering code base]:

```
    #include <iostream>

enum WindingOrder {
    // the RIGHT most 4-bits indicate the selection index from input[] to output[0]
    // the LEFT most 4-bits indicate the selection index from input[] to output[3]
    BOTTOM = 0x1210,
    RIGHT = 0x3212,
    TOP = 0x3230,
    LEFT = 0x3010
};

void BitwiseWind(int const *input, int *output, unsigned short edge)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        output[i] = input[(edge >> (i*4)) & 0x000F];    // decode
}

int main() {
    enum WindingOrder edges[4] = { BOTTOM, RIGHT, TOP, LEFT };
    int rect[4] = { 1, 3, 4, 5 };
    int output[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        BitwiseWind(rect, output, edges[i]);
        std::cout << output[0] << output[1] << output[2] << output[3] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The generic getIndex(int i,enum WindingOrder edge) would be:

```
int getIndex(int i,enum WindingOrder edge)
{
   return ((edge >> (i*4)) & 0x000F);
}
```

I did not count how many instruction it used , but i believe it would be quiet few. And really easy to image how it worked. :)

Comment: @Jonathan Mee   , would you mind to tell me your opinion about this answer?

Comment: Definitely the best implementation of chqrlie's answer.

Comment: @Reader This [will fail](http://ideone.com/EAmRsL) the tester I wrote, but not because it's bad code, just because the point order is reversed. This is permitted in the question. I am accepting this answer because even though not original it is the clearest way to understand and implement [chqrlie's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34426850/2642059).

Comment: @Ju-HsienLai:  kudos to you! 18 instructions for `BitWiseWind`. `enum WindingOrder` has become a bit cryptic and hardcoded for one specific task, but nonetheless a clever solution.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a different solution. It is a variation on the static array approach, but without an actual array: the indexing matrix is inlined as a 32 bit unsigned integer computed as constant expression. The column for the `edge` parameter is selected with a single shift, finally, individual indices for each array element are selected with via simple bit-shifting and masking.

This solution has some advantages:

- it is simple to understand
- it does not use tests
- it does not use a static array, nor any other memory location
- it is independent on the winding order and can be easily customized for any array component order
- it does not use C99 specific syntax, which may not be available in C++.

This is as close as I could get to a *bitwise solution*.

```
#include <iostream>

enum WindingOrder { BOTTOM = 0, RIGHT, TOP, LEFT };

void BitwiseWind(int const *input, int *output, enum WindingOrder edge)
{
    unsigned bits = ((0x00010201 << BOTTOM * 2) |
                     (0x02010203 << RIGHT  * 2) |
                     (0x02030003 << TOP    * 2) |
                     (0x00030001 << LEFT   * 2))
                    >> (edge * 2);

    output[0] = input[(bits >> 24) & 3];
    output[1] = input[(bits >> 16) & 3];
    output[2] = input[(bits >>  8) & 3];
    output[3] = input[(bits >>  0) & 3];
}

int main() {
    enum WindingOrder edges[4] = { BOTTOM, RIGHT, TOP, LEFT };
    int rect[4] = { 1, 3, 4, 5 };
    int output[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        BitwiseWind(rect, output, edges[i]);
        std::cout << output[0] << output[1] << output[2] << output[3] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling `BitwiseWind` for `x86-64` with `clang -O3` generates 21 instructions, 6 more than the static array version, but without any memory reference. That's a little disappointing, but I hope it could generate fewer instructions for an `ARM` target, taking advantage of bit-field extraction opcodes.  Incidentally, the inlined version using `output[i] = array[(i+(i==winding)*2)&3];` produces 25 instructions without any jumps, and `gcc -O3` does much worse: it generates a lot more code with 4 tests and jumps.

The generic `getIndex` function below compiles to just 6 `x86` instructions:

```
int getIndex(int i, int edge) {
    return (((0x00010201 << BOTTOM * 2) |
             (0x02010203 << RIGHT  * 2) |
             (0x02030003 << TOP    * 2) |
             (0x00030001 << LEFT   * 2))
            >> (edge * 2 + 24 - i * 8)) & 3;
}
```

Comment: I don't get a C99 syntax warning. I also don't see anything that looks non-standard. What were you seeing that's a problem?

Comment: It seems C99 designated intializers are a `g++` and/or `clang` extension not condoned by the C++ standard.  I had to compile Jimbo's code with `-Wno-c99-extensions` to slience `clang` warnings. When I advised Jimbo to use designated initializers to increase portability, I had no idea the C++ guys had been consistently refusing this useful C99 improvement for the past 15 years.

Comment: @JonathanMee: I forgot to say I compile with `c++ -Weverything` and a few extra configuration flags.  With this, `clang` complains about non C++ standard C99 syntax extensions.

Comment: Although not exactly what I expected from a bitwise solution it would be hard to argue that this isn't the most innovative clever solution proposed. For this reason I'm awarding this solution the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a particular reason that this needs to use lots of bitwise operations? It seems quite a complex way to solve the problem?

You seem to be quite worried about speed, for example, you don't want to use modulo because it is expensive. This being the case, why not just use a really simple lookup and unroll the loops? [***Example on ideone as well.***](https://ideone.com/HODhP9)

EDIT: Thanks to **chqrlie** for input. Have updated answer accordingly.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum WindingOrder {
    BOTTOM = 0,
    RIGHT,
    TOP,
    LEFT
};

void DoWinding1(unsigned int const *const in, unsigned int *const out, const enum WindingOrder ord)
{
    static const unsigned int order[4][4] = { [BOTTOM] = {0,1,2,1},
                                              [RIGHT]  = {2,1,2,3},
                                              [TOP]    = {2,3,0,3},
                                              [LEFT]   = {0,3,0,1} };
    out[0] = in[order[ord][0]]; 
    out[1] = in[order[ord][1]];
    out[2] = in[order[ord][2]];
    out[3] = in[order[ord][3]];
}


int main() {
    unsigned int idx;
    unsigned int rect[4] = {1, 3, 4, 5};
    unsigned int out[4] = {0};

    DoWinding1(rect, out, BOTTOM);

    std::cout << out[0] << out[1] << out[2] << out[3] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity.  Probably very efficient too, only 15 basic instructions for the whole thing.  You should constify the `order` array and you could make this independent on the particular `WindingOrder` by using the C99 designated intializers:  `{ [BOTTOM]={0,1,2,1}, ...}`

Comment: Good point about making the array const and the winding order, thank you. I'll update the answer with that.

Comment: @Jimbo This is a great answer, and I've given a +1. What I'm curious about is doing this dynamically though.

Comment: @JonathanMee Thanks... how do you mean dynamically? Does the problem extend to other shapes or something like that?

Comment: @Jimbo Guilty as charged! I was hoping to find a dynamic pattern that I could extend according to the number of sides. I'm not sure if that's possible yet, but I'm starting with a square simplification to see if anything jumps out at me.

Comment: @Jimbo: I'm afraid there is a typo in the initializer: it should read `[TOP]    = {2,3,0,3},`

Comment: @chqrlie yes your right, thank you for a second time :)

Comment: @JonathanMee: The extension of the problem is a little harder because it depends on how you specify an arbitrary polygon. Could you expand on your specification of the problem please?

Comment: @Jimbo Thanks for the interest! I'm really curious what could be thought up in this space, but to change the problem is unfair to the other answer, and anyone who is working on a solution. I will probably ask a follow up question once I have clearly defined the parameters in my mind. For now though, this is really an academic question. Not looking for the best way to find a coordinate of an edge (I believe your solution is already the best way to do that), but specifically looking for a bit-wise way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

This is untested and there might be a small mistake in some details but the general idea should work.

Copying the array to the output would use the indices `{0,1,2,3}`. To get a specific edge you have to do some transformations to the indices:

```
                    changed_pos  changed_to
RIGHT : {2,1,2,3}       0           2
TOP   : {0,3,2,3}       1           3
LEFT  : {0,1,0,3}       2           0
BOTTOM: {0,1,2,1}       3           1
```

So basically you have to add `2 mod 4` for the specific position of your winding.
So the (like I said untested) snipped could look like this

```
for (size_t i=0; i<4; ++i) {
    output[i] = array[(i+(i==edge)*2)%4];
}
```

If the comparison is true you add `1*2=2`, else `0*2=0` to the index and do `mod 4` to stay in the range.

Your `enum` have to look like this (but I guess you figured this out by yourself):

```
enum WindingOrder {
    RIGHT,
    TOP,
    LEFT,
    BOTTOM
};
```

[MWE](http://ideone.com/ZwBuv6):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum WindingOrder {
    RIGHT=0,
    TOP,
    LEFT,
    BOTTOM
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> array = {2,4,8,9};
    std::vector<int> output(4);

    std::vector<WindingOrder> test = {LEFT,RIGHT,BOTTOM,TOP};
    for (auto winding : test) {
        for (size_t i=0; i<4; ++i) {
            output[i] = array[(i+(i==winding)*2)%4];
        }
        std::cout << "winding " << winding << ": " << output[0] << output[1] << output[2] << output[3] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you are not accepting this answer?

Comment: I'm cooking one. I want to finish my solution and compare. Modulus is an expensive operation. Fear not, if this is the best solution tomorrow, I will accept.

Comment: I am not sure whether or not mod is expensive but in this case its mod 4. You can easily replace it by `x & 3`.

Comment: Fascinating. You are correct: http://ideone.com/0QuxvA Now, tell me can you do anything to turn the conditional into a bitwise op? (`i == winding`) Cause that's essentially rolling an `if` statement into your math. The code compiles to the same thing as: `output[i] = (i == winding ? array[(i + 2) & 3] : array[i & 3]);` It's clever but it's still an `if`.

Comment: An XOR `i^winding` is zero if they are equal but something "random" if they are not. Maybe we can build on that?

Comment: Sounds promising, but we'd have to do better than "random". Still banging my head against the wall on how to get my solution to work. Hopefully I'll have something to post shortly

Comment: Is `array[(i+(!(i-winding))*2)&3]` producing a branch as well?
Or to get ridiculous `array[(i+((!(i-winding))<<1))&3]`?

Comment: Yeah, `!` is a logical operator, to invert bits you need to use the bit-wise operator: `~` but that will invert all your bits which I don't think you want. Your conditional here is: `i - winding != 0` For example: `(!(0 - 3)) * 2` returns `0`, so obviously we're not doing regular math here.

Comment: The logical operator `!` does exactly what we want. If the two numbers are  equal the difference is 0 which is negated 1. If they are unequal the result is "something not 0" which is negated 0.

Comment: The logical operator is a conditional (it's doing an `if`-statement for you). What we want is something that works without conditionals: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34343110/2642059

Comment: @JonathanMee: why are you so turned off by logical operators?  did you look at the compiled code?  `==` and `!` compile to code without jumps on modern compiler/target combinations.  try http://gcc.godbolt.org/#

Comment: @chqrlie Just a logic exercise. I wanted to see if I could do it. Now I want to see if I can do it better.

Comment: @JonathanMee `% 4` is not an "expensive operation" . Based on your question you seem to have a lot of misconceptions about C.   Writing obfuscated bit-hacks is a bit of fun but in reality you would not use any of the posted solutions: they make your code harder to read and maintain, without any performance gain.  "how few bit-wise operations could be taken" has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: @M.M `%` is typically a more expensive operation than say `&`, though I'm sure the compiler will simplify `% 4` to `& 3`. As far as the rest of your criticism, I don't know what to say, I guess: "Don't let it bother you that I want to do something to find a purely academic answer."

Answer (score 1):

From the answer of yourself, you're close to the solution. I think what you need here is [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), which is a universal method for most Boolean algebra problems.

Suppose

> The elements of the array then respectively define:
>
> ```
> input[0]: Left edge's X coordinate
> input[0]: Bottom edge's Y coordinate
> input[0]: Right edge's X coordinate
> input[0]: Top edge's Y coordinate
> ```
>
> I have defined the a winding order in this enum:
>
> ```
> enum WindingOrder {
>     BOTTOM = 0,
>     RIGHT,
>     TOP,
>     LEFT
> };
> ```

Since the for-loop may looks like

```
for (int k = 0; k != 4; ++k) {
    int i = getIndex(k, edge); // calculate i from k and edge
    output[k] = square[i];
}
```

Then the input is `k`(`output[k]`) and `edge`, the output is `i`(`square[i]`). And because `i` has 2 bits, then two logic functions are needed.

Here we use `P = F1(A, B, C, D)` and `Q = F2(A, B, C, D)` to represent the logic functions, in which `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `P` and `Q` are all single bit, and

```
k    = (A << 1) + B;
edge = (C << 1) + D;
i    = (P << 1) + Q;
```

Then what we need to do is just deduce the two logic functions `F1` and `F2` from the given conditions.

From the switch case statements you gave, we can easily get the truth table.

```
k\edge  0   1   3   2
    0   0   2   0   2
    1   1   1   3   3
    3   1   3   1   3
    2   2   2   0   0
```

Then separate this into two truth table for two bits `P` and `Q`.

```
P   edge    0   1   3   2
k   AB\CD   00  01  11  10
0      00   0   1   0   1
1      01   0   0   1   1
3      11   0   1   0   1
2      10   1   1   0   0

Q   edge    0   1   3   2
k   AB\CD   00  01  11  10
0      00   0   0   0   0
1      01   1   1   1   1
3      11   1   1   1   1
2      10   0   0   0   0
```

These are the Karnaugh maps that I mentioned at the beginning. We can easily get the functions.

```
F1(A, B, C, D) = A~B~C + A~CD + ~B~CD + ~ABC + ~AC~D + BC~D
F2(A, B, C, D) = B
```

Then the program will be

```
int getIndex(int k, int edge) {
    int A = (k >> 1) & 1;
    int B = k & 1;
    int C = (edge >> 1) & 1;
    int D = edge & 1;
    int P = A&~B&~C | A&~C&D | ~B&~C&D | ~A&B&C | ~A&C&~D | B&C&~D;
    int Q = B;
    return (P << 1) + Q;
}
```

Passed the examine [here](http://ideone.com/ji5I8T). Of course, you can simplify the function even more with the XOR.

---

**EDIT**

Using XOR to simplify the expression can be achieved most of time, since `A^B == A~B + ~AB`. But this may not the thing you want. First, I think the performance varies only a little between the [**Sum of Products(SoP)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form) expression and the even more simplified version with XOR. Second, there is not a universal method (as far as I know) to simplify an expression with XOR, so you have to rely on your own experience to do this work.

There are sixteen possible logic functions of two variables, but in digital logic hardware, the simplest gate circuits implement only four of them: AND, OR, and the complements of those (NAND and NOR). And the Karnaugh map are used to simplify real-world logic requirements so that they can be implemented using a minimum number of physical logic gates.

There are two common expressions used here, *Sum of Products* and *Product of Sums* expressions. These two expressions can be implemented directly using **only** AND and OR logic operators. And they can be deduced directly with Karnaugh map.

Comment: This solution is the only one that attempts to answer the question that I wanted answered: "Is my solution the best way to solve the problem using bitwise operators?" Including shifts I do 15 operations. This solution does 34. C++ doesn't provide a nand operation but since assembly does, surely 6 of these operations would be simplified away. You mention, "You can simplify the function even more with the XOR." Perhaps if this is done you can get below 15 operations?

Comment: @JonathanMee See the edited answer above. And your solution may be the simplest in according to number of operations for this problem :)

Comment: I know that there are x86 instructions for binary operations beyond `AND`, `OR`, `NAND`, and `NOR`. Perhaps you're suggesting that the underlying RISC processor only has these operations? Unfortunately I believe that's also false :( I'm probably just misunderstanding what you're saying here.

Answer (score 1):

If you define the coordinates and directions in clockwise order starting at left,

```
#define  LEFT   0
#define  TOP    1
#define  RIGHT  2
#define  BOTTOM 3
```

you can use

```
void edge_line(int line[4], const int rect[4], const int edge)
{
    line[0] = rect[   edge      & 2      ];
    line[1] = rect[ ((edge + 3) & 2) + 1 ];
    line[2] = rect[ ((edge + 1) & 2)     ];
    line[3] = rect[  (edge      & 2) + 1 ];
}
```

to copy the edge line coordinates (each line segment in clockwise winding order). It looks suboptimal, but using `-O2`, GCC-4.8, you get essentially

```
edge_line:
        pushl   %esi
        pushl   %ebx
        movl    20(%esp), %ecx
        movl    16(%esp), %edx
        movl    12(%esp), %eax
        movl    %ecx, %esi
        andl    $2, %esi
        movl    (%edx,%esi,4), %ebx
        movl    %ebx, (%eax)
        leal    3(%ecx), %ebx
        addl    $1, %ecx
        andl    $2, %ebx
        andl    $2, %ecx
        addl    $1, %ebx
        movl    (%edx,%ebx,4), %ebx
        movl    %ebx, 4(%eax)
        movl    (%edx,%ecx,4), %ecx
        movl    %ecx, 8(%eax)
        movl    4(%edx,%esi,4), %edx
        movl    %edx, 12(%eax)
        popl    %ebx
        popl    %esi
        ret
```

but on 64-bit, even better

```
edge_line:
        movl    %edx, %ecx
        andl    $2, %ecx
        movslq  %ecx, %rcx
        movl    (%rsi,%rcx,4), %eax
        movl    %eax, (%rdi)
        leal    3(%rdx), %eax
        addl    $1, %edx
        andl    $2, %edx
        andl    $2, %eax
        movslq  %edx, %rdx
        cltq
        movl    4(%rsi,%rax,4), %eax
        movl    %eax, 4(%rdi)
        movl    (%rsi,%rdx,4), %eax
        movl    %eax, 8(%rdi)
        movl    4(%rsi,%rcx,4), %eax
        movl    %eax, 12(%rdi)
        ret
```

As you can see, there are no conditionals, and the binary operators combine and optimize to very few instructions.

Edited to add:

If we define a `getIndex(i, edge)` function, using three binary ANDs, one bit shift (right by 1), three additions, and one subtraction,

```
int getIndex(const int i, const int edge)
{
    return (i & 1) + ((edge + 4 - (i & 1) + (i >> 1)) & 2);
}
```

with which `edge_line()` can be implemented as

```
void edge_line(int line[4], const int rect[4], const int edge)
{
    line[0] = rect[ getIndex(0, edge) ];
    line[1] = rect[ getIndex(1, edge) ];
    line[2] = rect[ getIndex(2, edge) ];
    line[3] = rect[ getIndex(3, edge) ];
}
```

we get the exact same results as before. Using GCC-4.8.4 and `-O2` on AMD64/x86-64 compiles to

```
getIndex:
        movl    %edi, %edx
        sarl    %edi
        andl    $1, %edx
        subl    %edx, %esi
        leal    4(%rsi,%rdi), %eax
        andl    $2, %eax
        addl    %edx, %eax
        ret
```

and to

```
getIndex:
        movl    4(%esp), %eax
        movl    8(%esp), %edx
        movl    %eax, %ecx
        andl    $1, %ecx
        subl    %ecx, %edx
        sarl    %eax
        leal    4(%edx,%eax), %eax
        andl    $2, %eax
        addl    %ecx, %eax
        ret
```

on i686.  Note that I arrived at the above form using the four-by-four result table; there are other, more rigorous ways to construct it, and there might even be a more optimal form.  Because of this, I seriously recommend adding a big huge comment above the function, explaining the intent, and preferably also showing the result table. Something like

```
/* This function returns an array index:
 *    0  for left
 *    1  for top
 *    2  for right
 *    3  for bottom
 * given edge:
 *    0  for left
 *    1  for top
 *    2  for right
 *    3  for bottom
 * and i:
 *    0  for initial x
 *    1  for initial y
 *    2  for final x
 *    3  for final y
 *
 * The result table is
 *     |  edge
 *     | 0 1 2 3
 * ----+-------
 * i=0 | 0 0 2 2
 * i=1 | 3 1 1 3
 * i=2 | 0 2 2 0
 * i=3 | 1 1 3 3
 *
 * Apologies for the write-only code.
*/
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Interesting, but an incomplete solution. There is no simple way to turn it into `int getIndex(int i, int edge)` In fact this solution has already proposed and deleted because the author found the additional logic needed to solve for `i` made this solution inferior to [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34343110/2642059) If you have a better way to solve for `i` without conditionals I'd love to see it though.

Comment: @JonathanMee: I didn't see `getIndex()` described in your question; that's why I ignored it. I've edited my answer to show how simple a `getIndex()` function you can use in this scheme (eight arithmetic operations).

Answer (score 0):

Lets call our goal variable to be used to index `squared`: `int index`.

Now we'll create a table of the desired `index` for `edge` versus `i`, with `edge` across the row and `i` down the column:

```
 ║0│1│2│3
═╬═╪═╪═╪═
0║0│1│2│1
─╫─┼─┼─┼─
1║2│1│2│3
─╫─┼─┼─┼─
2║2│3│0│3
─╫─┼─┼─┼─
3║0│3│0│1
```

It is obvious from this that the least significant bit of `index` is always odd for odd `i`s and even for even `i`s. So if we could find the most significant bit of `index` we'd just to or that with `i & 1` and we'd have our `index`. So lets make another table of just the most significant bit of `index` for the same `edge` versus `i` table:

```
 ║0│1│2│3
═╬═╪═╪═╪═
0║0│0│1│0
─╫─┼─┼─┼─
1║1│0│1│1
─╫─┼─┼─┼─
2║1│1│0│1
─╫─┼─┼─┼─
3║0│1│0│0
```

We can see several things here:

1. When `i` is `0` or `3` the columns are identical depending only on `edge`

   - These columns are set when `edge` is `1` or `2`
2. When `i` is `1` or `2` the columns are inverse of each other

   - These columns are set when only `edge`'s most significant bit or only `i`'s most significant bit is set

So let's start by breaking `edge` and `i` into least significant and most significant bits:

```
const int ib0 = i & 1;
const int ib1 = (i & 2) >> 1;
const int eb0 = edge & 1;
const int eb1 = (edge & 2) >> 1;
```

From here we can easily find whether `i` is `0` or `3`:

```
const int iXor = ib0 ^ ib1;
```

For the `0`/`3` condition:

```
const int iXorCondition = ib1 ^ eb1;
```

And the `1`/`2` condition:

```
const int iNXorCondition = eb0 ^ eb1;
```

Now we'll just need to combine those with their respective `iXor` and put back `index`'s least significant bit:

```
const int index = ((iNXorCondition & ~iXor | iXorCondition & iXor) << 1) | ib0;
```

Putting this all together into a convenient function we get:

```
int getIndex(int i, int edge) {
    const int ib0 = i & 1;
    const int ib1 = (i & 2) >> 1;
    const int eb0 = edge & 1;
    const int eb1 = (edge & 2) >> 1;

    const int iXor = ib0 ^ ib1;

    const int iNXorCondition = eb0 ^ eb1;
    const int iXorCondition = ib1 ^ eb1;

    return ((iNXorCondition & ~iXor | iXorCondition & iXor) << 1) | ib0;
}
```

I've written a checking live example [here](http://ideone.com/EeWvoO).

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to know is can I construct the square indexes to assign to output in a for loop, without an if/case/ternary statement (in other words using bit-wise operations) ?

I would ask you what you expect to achieve in doing that ?

My view is that the `switch-case` construct will, typically, be completely reorganized by a compiler's optimization code.  It's best, IMO, to leave that code alone and let the compiler do that.

There are only two conditions where Id change that view ;

- You were writing in OpenCL ( rather than C ) and wanted to optimize the code where decision-branch logic can be problematic for performance.
- You wanted to use explicit coding for SIMD vectorization.  There are some special operations that *might* help there, but it's a coding option that locks you into things that might not work well on hardware without SIMD instruction sets ( or perform quite differently on different hardware ).  It's also worth noting that some compilers can auto-vectorize with the right coding.

I just see little or no advantage to coding these operations any other way than `switch-case` for C.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to achieve that:

```
do {
    output[i] = square[
                (edge & 1) * (
                    !(i & 1) * ((edge + 1) & 2) + 
                    (i & 1) * (
                        (!((edge - 1)/2)&1) * i + 
                        (((edge - 1)/2)&1) * (4-i)
                    )
                ) +     
                !(edge & 1) * (
                    (i & 1) * (edge + 1) + 
                    !(i & 1) * ((edge & 2) - ((edge & 2)-1) * i)
                )
                ];
} while(++i <= LEFT);
```

To help you understand I indented the code, you can obviously erase all the white spaces. I have put a tab where ever I wanted to separate two cases. By the way as you see the calculation is in two sections for two different cases which are symmetrical but I solved each case with a different algorithm so you can see various ways to achieve things.

Comment: The `!` operator is a conditional operator. This solution is effectively doing inline `if`-statements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334828/dynamically-find-the-edge-of-a-rectangle/34470738#comment56423327_34336130